# Set table on model for get last record - laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

I need to set dynamically the table name (extract from other database) and get the last record.

This is my model:

```
class Project extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'myconn';
    protected $table = '';

}
```

I tried that way (in other class):

```
$last = Project::table($tableName)->orderBy('upload_time', 'desc')->first();
```

But this is the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `setTable` instead of `table`? See [the relevant method in the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1071)

Answer (score 0):

The `Eloquent query` is like:

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
               ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

but you are using it like `Query Builder` way, i.e.

```
DB::table('tablename')->orderBy('id', desc)->first();
```

which is wrong.

Comment: What solution do you recommend?

Comment: Use it like `Eloquent query` example defined in answer

Comment: ok, but how set the table name? 'active' is  the name of the column

Answer (score 0):

you can use query builder

DB::table($tableName)->orderBy('upload_time', 'desc')->first();

Comment: Thanks, but the default table isn't 'myconn', but other: 'users'.
So the error is:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'users.tablename' doesn't exist ...